# Error when trying to name an object using a loop

Tags: java, oop

So I have this list of names that gets passed in to a Tribe object, and I want to make a new Member object that can be accessed by that name as well as pass in that same name for the for each name using a loop. But when I use this code

```
  public Tribe(String tribeName, String[] nameLst){
        this.tribeName = tribeName;
        this.nameLst = nameLst;

    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        members[i] = nameLst[i];
        Member nameLst[i] = new Member(nameLst[i]);
     }
     }
```

I get the error that nameLst was already declared, the same happens when i set nameLst[i] equal to a new variable. How else can I name these new objects dynamically? Using the same logic in python worked perfectly.

Comment: What exactly do you want the line `Member nameLst[i] = new Member(nameLst[i]);` to do? What do you think the leading `Member` does? What type of object does the `nameLst` array contain? If you answer those questions you may understand what's happening.

Comment: Java doesn't have dynamic variable names. You might want to use a Map to associate a name with a Member.

Comment: You have clashing variable names: constructor argument `String[] nameList` and local variable `Member nameLst[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array with data type of **Member**.

```
Member[] memData = new Member[10];
    
for (int i=0; i < nameLst.length; i++){
     members[i] = nameLst[i];
     memData[i] = new Member(nameLst[i]);
}

for(int i=0; i < memData.length; i++){
     System.out.println(memData[i]);
}
```

The name is send to new Member constructor to store it. You could add more Member data other than name to make use of it, and I would recommend you to use ArrayList if possible.

For the Member class, it would be something like this. toString method overrided to print out the **memData[i]** in proper way:

```
class Member{

    String name;

    public Member(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: " + name; 
    }
}
```

To access individual methods, you could simply use **arrayName[index].methodName**:

```
System.out.println("Method to get 2nd name: " + memData[1].getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, naming arrays "l[ist]" is ... well, something I wouldn't do. If you imply a datatype, do it either consistent or just use a plural noun like names.

Other than that - I will point out your obvious mistakes:

The for loop should (normally) iterate over the length of an array, not over a predefined number unless you want that limitation that a tribe can only have 10 members. If not, use `for(int i = 0; i<nameLst.length; i++)`.

The error you're getting is because you're trying to define a variable with the name   `nameLst[i]` - the name `nameLst` however is already taken by the context. To create a new member, you'd write it like the following:

```
Member member = new Member(nameLst[i]);
```

However, due to the scope, this variable will only be visible within the loop. You need to declare an array of the Member type in your class first and then add the member to the array with:

```
memberArr[i] = new Member(nameLst[i]);
```

Comment: So then as I iterate through the loop will all the members just be called member? then how do i access each individual member's methods?